# How can I use Dependency Injection to pass Application() to ViewModel() using Hilt in Android Studio?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I 'm using Hilt  as Dependency Injection,  I hope to DI `class UIApp` into `class SoundViewModel`, so I use  `fun provideUIApp(): UIApp {...}` as the following code.

I  know `Application()` is a special class in Android , I don't know whether the way below is good,  could you tell me ?

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class UIApp : Application() {
    fun log(){
        Log.e("my","Server")
    }
}

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {  
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUIApp(): UIApp {
        return UIApp()
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(         
    private val myapp: UIApp,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is not gonna to work. Remove the ObjectModule and read about @ApplicationContext annotation.

Comment: You can't just construct an `Application` object like that, and why would you want to? If you're using your own custom `Application` class, you need to add it to the manifest, and then when your app runs it will *use* that class. Then when you get an `Application` object passed to you (e.g. provided by a `@HiltViewModel` if added in the constructor, or by subclassing `AndroidViewModel`) then - as far as I'm aware - you should be able to cast it to your custom application type, since that's what it is. But you generally don't need them - sure you don't just want a general singleton dependency?

Comment: Thanks! But the code above can be compiled.

Comment: Why you are trying to inject an application class insist HILT already has @ApplicationContext available to get app context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is relatively ok. The only issue with it is the way you are providing the App in the module.

As you are running your code inside the application, you already have the application, so you don't have to create it via constructor(I am not talking about tests in this case)

There are two main ways to provide the Application class in your case(there are more, but I won't describe them)

1. As you are using the Hilt and your Application class is already annotated by Hilt annotation, it means that you already have your application provided to the `SingletonComponent` in the form of context. You can retrieve it via [`@ApplicationContext`](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#predefined-qualifiers) annotation like:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(         
    @ApplicationContext private val myappContext: Context,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {
   val myApp = myappContext as UIApp
   // use myApp as a link to your actual UIApp
}
```

2. If you don't want to go with casting for some reason you can create a static variable in your app and initialize it in the onCreate method of your Application class and then provide it instead of creating another instance of the App class via constructor. It will look something like this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class UIApp : Application() {
    companion object{
       @JvmStatic
       lateinit var instance: UIApp
    }

    override func onCreate(){
        instance = this
    }
}

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {  
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUIApp(): UIApp {
        return UIApp.instance
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to reference your Application class in the manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".UIApp"
        ...>
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Application class is provided by default by hilt as `Context` instance, you can easily get it with `@ApplicationContext` and cast to your app class.

The cast will always succeed

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class UIApp : Application() {
    fun log(){
        Log.e("my","Server")
    }
}

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {  
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUIApp(@ApplicationContext application: Context): UIApp {
        return application as UIApp
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(         
    private val myapp: UIApp,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {
   ...
}
```