# Will I get an instance use the way?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

Normally, I get an instance with Code A.

The Code B comes from the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201140/how-can-i-use-dependency-injection-to-pass-application-to-viewmodel-using-hi).

Maybe `UIApp.instance` will cause error before the `override func onCreate(){... }` is launched in `class UIApp`.

I don't know if `UIApp.instance` can get an instance, could you tell me ?

**Code A**

```
class Billing private constructor (
    private val mContext: Context,
    private val purchaseItem :String
) {

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: Billing? = null
        fun getInstance(mContext: Context, purchaseItem: String): Billing =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: Billing(mContext, purchaseItem).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
    }

}


val my = Billing.getInstance(mContext,purchaseItem)
```

**Code B**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class UIApp : Application() {
    companion object{
       @JvmStatic
       lateinit var instance: UIApp
    }

    override func onCreate(){
        instance = this
    }
}

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {  
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUIApp(): UIApp {
        return UIApp.instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code B works because the Application class’s `onCreate()` function is the very first entry point of your app’s process. So long as you didn’t use `init` blocks or property initializers of the UIApp class to do so, it would be impossible to access the `instance` property before it is assigned. And since it is assigned in `onCreate()`, nothing else in your app has had an opportunity to start up other threads that might access it before it is assigned. Therefore, there is no need for thread synchronization or marking it volatile.

It looks like there’s a possible flaw in your design of Code B, though. It forces a `purchaseItem` parameter to be passed to the getter function, but it only uses this parameter the first time the function is called, and then all future calls will get an instance that uses that original value, even if they request a different value.